# Having Issues Printing Map to Cout

Tags: c++, dictionary, cout

How can I print a map of the following type: 
`map<string, vector<string>>`?

Everything I have tried so far has resulted in an error.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: @Sumeet Sorry I forgot to mention that specifically. I would like to print every key and its corresponding value in the map.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just implement :

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const map<string, vector<string>>& myMap)
```

One simple implementation might be.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const map<string, vector<string>>& myMap)
{
   for(auto elem : myMap)   {
       std::os << it->first << " -> ";
       auto & vec = it->second;
       for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
           os << vec[i] << " ";
       }
       os << "\n";    
   }
   os<<"\n";
   return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (tested in Visual Studio 2013).
Strictly speaking, you should include the code you tried yourself to solve the problem. You said everything you tried gave an error. Just post whatever you tried and the exact error you got.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    map<string, vector<string>> myMap;
    myMap["key1"] = { "m00", "m01", "m02" };
    myMap["key2"] = { "m10", "m11" };
    myMap["key3"] = { "m20", "m21", "m22", "m23" };

    for (auto m : myMap)
    {
        string const & key = m.first;
        vector<string>& v = m.second;
        cout << "Key=" << key.c_str();
        for (auto i : v)
            cout << " " << i.c_str();
        cout << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```